# push_back for adding a temporary container to another container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm writing a `push_back` function for adding a temporary container to another container .

And it should resize or reserve container before using push_back(and also it should prefer reserve over resize if both of them available)

Current code is :

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class>
    struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};

    template<class T, class A0>
    static auto test_reserve(int)
        ->sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>().reserve(std::declval<A0>()))>;
    template<class, class A0>
    static auto test_reserve(long)->std::false_type;

    template<class T, class A0>
    static auto test_resize(int)
        ->sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>().resize(std::declval<A0>()))>;
    template<class, class A0>
    static auto test_resize(long)->std::false_type;
}

//check if class T have reserve(Arg) function
template<class T, class Arg>
struct HasReserve : decltype(detail::test_reserve<T, Arg>(0)){};


//check if class T have resize(Arg) function
template<class T, class Arg>
struct HasResize : decltype(detail::test_resize<T, Arg>(0)){};

//enable if resize function exists and there is no reserve function
template<class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<HasResize< T1, typename T1::size_type>::value &&
    (!HasReserve< T1, typename T1::value_type>::value), void>::type
    inline reserveOrResize(T1& dst, T2&& src, typename T2::size_type newSize){
        static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference<T1&>::value, "You must pass lvalue_refrence as first parameter");
        static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<T2&&>::value, "You must pass rvalue_refrence as second parameter");
        int loc = dst.size() + 1;
        dst.resize(newSize);
        std::cout << "Resizing\n";
        for (auto&& elem : src){
            dst[loc++] = std::move(elem);
        }
}

//enable if  reserve function exists
template<class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<HasReserve< T1, typename T1::size_type>::value, void>::type
inline reserveOrResize(T1& dst, T2&& src, typename T2::size_type newSize){
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference<T1&>::value, "You must pass lvalue_refrence as first parameter");
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<T2&&>::value, "You must pass rvalue_refrence as second parameter");
    dst.reserve(newSize);
    std::cout << "Reserving\n";
    for (auto&& elem : src){
        dst.push_back(std::move(elem));
    }
}

//push_back container T2 at the end of Container T1
//T2 must be rvalue refrence
template<class T1, class T2>
void push_back(T1& dst, T2&& src){
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference<T1&>::value, "You must pass lvalue_refrence as first parameter");
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<T2&&>::value, "You must pass rvalue_refrence as second parameter");
    reserveOrResize(dst, std::move(src), src.size());
}
```

It works *fine* with containers with vector of simple types for example `std::vector<int>`

```
std::vector<int> vec;
push_back(vec,std::vector<int>(10));
```

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7891279a732928ec)

But When I use it with a vector of class it does not compile

```
struct A{};
int main(){   
    std::vector<A> vec;
    push_back(vec,std::vector<A>(10));//error
}
```

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e8186ca7a982587)

The error is :

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void push_back(T1&, T2&&) [with T1 = std::vector<A> T2 = 
std::vector<A>]':
main.cpp:74:35:   required from here
main.cpp:67:49: error: call of overloaded 'reserveOrResize(std::vector<A>&, std::remove_reference<std::vector<A>&>::type, std::vector<A>::size_type)' is ambiguous
  reserveOrResize(dst, std::move(src), src.size());
                                                 ^
main.cpp:67:49: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:37:9: note: typename std::enable_if<(HasResize<T1, typename T1::size_type>::value && (! HasReserve<T1, typename T1::value_type>::value)), void>::type reserveOrResize(T1&, T2&&, typename T2::size_type) [with T1 = std::vector<A> T2 = std::vector<A> typename std::enable_if<(HasResize<T1, typename T1::size_type>::value && (! HasReserve<T1, typename T1::value_type>::value)), void>::type = void; typename T2::size_type = long unsigned int]
  inline reserveOrResize(T1& dst, T2&& src, typename T2::size_type newSize){
         ^
main.cpp:51:8: note: typename std::enable_if<HasReserve<T1, typename T1::size_type>::value, void>::type reserveOrResize(T1&, T2&&, typename T2::size_type) [with T1 = std::vector<A> T2 = std::vector<A> typename std::enable_if<HasReserve<T1, typename T1::size_type>::value, void>::type = void; typename T2::size_type = long unsigned int]
 inline reserveOrResize(T1& dst, T2&& src, typename T2::size_type newSize){
    ^
```

Why it fails in the second example ?!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is here

```
(!HasReserve< T1, typename T1::value_type>::value), void>::type
```

should be `typename T1::size_type`, not `value_type`, since with `value_type` you are trying to check, that container has method reserve with argument of type `T1::value_type` (`struct A` in your case), since there is no such method in vector, both functions are available.